# Simplest way to convert a JSON object to a newly structured JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've got a JSON object that is structured like this:

```
{
    "xaxis": [
        "foo",
        "bar",
        "baz"
    ],
    "yaxis": [
        333,
        992,
        1365
    ]
}
```

From it I'd like to create another JSON object stuctured like this:

```
{ 
    "piegraph": [
        ["foo",333], 
        ["bar",992], 
        ["baz",1365]
    ] 
}
```

Doing this conversion in client-side JavaScript would save me additional development and another server round-trip to fetch what is essentially the same data.

I can employ the jQuery library if that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your first *JSON string* is already parsed to an object, you just have to iterate over the elements of any of the two arrays, to build the result:

```
var result = { piegraph: [] }; // initialize piegraph as an empty array

var l = obj.xaxis.length;
while(l--) {
  result.piegraph[l] = [ obj.xaxis[l], obj.yaxis[l] ];
}

// result will look like this:
// {"piegraph":[["foo",333],["bar",992],["baz",1365]]}
```

No libraries needed, just a plain sequential loop. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Functional JavaScript](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/):

```
second = { piegraph: Functional.zip([first.xaxis, first.yaxis]) };
```

Comment: +10 for that link to that Functional treasure! Never came across this.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just use a for loop something like?

```
for(var i = 0; xaxis.length; i++){
  piegraph.push({xaxis[i], yaxis[i]);
}
```

Comment: +1 for a clean, simple solution. -1 for the curly brackets inside `push()`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't hard to do manually, but the [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) functional library has a bunch of very handy functions, including `.zip()`:

```
var piegraph = _.zip( obj.xaxis, obj.yaxis );
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to do pair-wise matching (aka "zipping") of two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Assume array1  and array2 for x and y axes and resultArray i.e. "piegraph"

```
jQuery.map(array1, function(item, i){
    resultArray.push(new Array(array[item, array2[i]));
}
});
```